# telerik - how to refresh child 1 window after child 2 window close

Tags: telerik, radwindow

Please help me!
I have 1 apsx page and 2 uc.
From aspx can open radwindow contain uc 1, from uc 1 can open uc 2. in aspx, i have:

```
function CloseRadWindow()
    {
        if(GetRadWindowManager().getActiveWindow() == null)
        {
            refreshGridGiaoDuToan(); //this one refresh aspx page from uc 1
        }
        else
        {
//i hope this one fresh uc1 after close uc2 but error
            var wnd2 = GetRadWindowManager().getWindowByName("wndPopup2");
            console.log(wnd2);
            wnd2.get_contentFrame().contentWindow.refreshGridNhiemVu();
        }

    }

    function refreshGridGiaoDuToan() {
        $find("<%= pnGiaoNganSach.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("SoGiao");
    }
```

On uc 1 i have

```
   function refreshGridNhiemVu() {
    alert("va");
    $find("<%= pnGiaoNganSachChiTiet.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RefreshNhiemVu");
}
```

But when i close uc 2, is always error: get_contentFrame().contentWindow.refreshGridNhiemVu is not funtion...

So my question is how to refresh (call function in codebehind) uc 1 after close uc2?
Please help me! Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this approach is correct. You must make sure the correct RadWindow instances are referenced and you can add some checks whether the function exists to avoid errors:

- see this on having several RadWindowManagers which may be a cause for wrong references: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-wrong-window-opened.html
- see here on creating the parent-child hierarchy: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/creating-parent-child-relationships-between-radwindows-and-passing-data-between-them
- here is a bunch of checks before calling the function that can avoid the error:

  ```
      if (wnd2.get_contentFrame && wnd2.get_contentFrame() &&
          wnd2.get_contentFrame().contentWindow &&
          wnd2.get_contentFrame().contentWindowrefreshGridNhiemVu) {
              wnd2.get_contentFrame().contentWindow.refreshGridNhiemVu();
      }
  ```

which you can extend with a typeof check to make sure the variable is a function before calling it.